# Why my code is not showing receiver message?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stream-builder

Receiver is unable to see receiver message. The sender can see his messages but he is unable to see receiver message. Can anyone solve my issue I think my query is correct but I can not solve my issue
.If the issue is with query please make the query in correct way.

Here is my database:

[image: doc1]

[image: doc2]

Here is my code

```
Expanded(
  child: StreamBuilder(
      stream:FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("messages") .where("senderid", isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
          .where("receiverid", isEqualTo: widget.id).orderBy("Date",descending: false).snapshots(),
      builder: (builder,AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>snapshot){
        if(!snapshot.hasData){
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
        }
        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (itemBuilder, index) {
              final message = snapshot.data!.docs[index]["message"];
              final senderId = snapshot.data!.docs[index]["senderid"];
              final currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
              final isMe = senderId == currentUser!.uid;
              final alignment = isMe ? MainAxisAlignment.end : MainAxisAlignment.start;
              final messageTextStyle = isMe ? TextStyle(color: Colors.white) : TextStyle(color: Colors.black);
              final messageColor = isMe ? Colors.blue : Colors.grey.shade300;
              return Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: alignment,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 8),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 16),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: messageColor,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: isMe ? Radius.circular(20) : Radius.circular(0),
                        topRight: isMe ? Radius.circular(0) : Radius.circular(20),
                        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                        bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      message,
                      style: messageTextStyle,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            });
      }),
),
```

```
IconButton(
    onPressed: ()async {
      print("ID=="+widget.id);
      if (messagecontroller.text.isNotEmpty) {
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("messages").add({
          "senderid":FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid,
          "receiverid":widget.id,
          "Date":DateTime.now(),
          "message":messagecontroller.text.toString(),
        }).whenComplete(() {

          Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Send message to ${widget.name}........."
              ,
              backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
              timeInSecForIosWeb: 1
          );
        });
        messagecontroller.clear();
      }
      else{
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Please Enter text to send message to ${widget.name}"
            ,
            backgroundColor: Colors.red
        );
      }
    },
    icon: Icon(Icons.send),
    color: Colors.grey,
  ),
```

Comment: Maybe your senderid id receiverid and vise versa to confirm that you can replace stream to this [snippet](https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#585ur4s2jfawxzfs6f8eq) due to limitation of characters posting as a snippet : ).

Comment: Again provide [minimal reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) steps to recreate the issue.

Comment: You are using boolean operator in stream builder but it create error